# How to optimize this code

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, query-optimization

I have used this code in helper to display the count based on the status -

```
    def to_do_count
        Task.where(status: 0).count
    end 

    def in_progress_count
        Task.where(status: 1).count
    end

    def paused_count
        Task.where(status: 2).count
    end

    def completed_count
        Task.where(status: 3).count
    end
```

I need help to optimize this code as there are lot of repetitions.

Comment: I did not know optimization could be done by these many ways, but I liked Pavel's option 1 approach.

Comment: should be moved into Review network

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
def task_count(status)
  Task
    .where(status: { to_do: 0, in_progress: 1, paused_count: 2, completed_count: 3 }[status])
    .count
end

task_count(:to_do) 
task_count(:in_progress)
```

**Option 2**

You can simplify it by using scopes

```
class Task
  scope :to_do,           -> { where(status: 0) }
  scope :in_progress,     -> { where(status: 1) }
  scope :paused_count,    -> { where(status: 2) }
  scope :completed_count, -> { where(status: 3) }
end
```

Then helper can look like this:

```
def task_count(status)
  Task.send(status).count
end

task_count(:to_do)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_of(type)
    Task.where(status: get_status_type(type)).count
end 

def get_status_type(type)
   {to_do: 0, in_progress: 1, paused_count: 2, completed_count: 3}[type]
end
```

Now call:

```
count_of(:to_do)
```

instead of

```
to_do_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Use hash constant

```
TASK = {
  to_do: 0,
  in_progress: 1,
  paused_count: 2,
  completed_count: 3
}

def self.count_of(type)
  Task.where(status: TASK[type]).count
end
```

Call it on class

```
Task.count_of(:to_do)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `STATUSES` constants then define those methods using runtime method definition in Ruby. The code will be like

```
STATUSES = {
  to_do:       0,
  in_progress: 1,
  paused:      2,
  completed:   3
}

def count_for(status)
  Task.where(status: status).count
end

STATUSES.each do |k, v|
  define_method("#{k}_count"){ count_for(v) }
end
```

Now you can call all these methods. Since they were defined dynamically

- to_do_count
- in_progress_count
- paused_count
- completed_count